# Adding jupyter_nbextensions_configurator to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Ultimately, I want a Notebook extension that has spell check. Following [this tutorial](https://nicoguaro.github.io/posts/ortografia_jupyter/) I tried to install the [`jupyter_nbextensions_configurator`](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator)

However, it doesn't seem to have been enabled as I never see the "Nbextensions" tab as promised.

### Steps I took:

Installed pip package

```
pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

Enabled the server extension with the command:

```
➜ jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user  # can be skipped for notebook >=5.3
Enabling: jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
- Writing config: /home/hofbr/.jupyter
    - Validating...
      jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.6.1 OK
Enabling notebook nbextension nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main...
Enabling tree nbextension nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main...
```

Refreshed my `.zshrc`

Yet, when opening up a fresh notebook (after shutting down all other jupyter environments) I still never see this fabled `Nbextensions` tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can downgrade Jupyter Notebook to an earlier version, you can follow these steps:

```bash
pip uninstall jupyter notebook

pip install jupyter notebook==6.4.3 (this will install Jupyter Notebook version 6.4.3).

# After the installation is complete, you can use the following command to check the version of Jupyter Notebook
jupyter notebook --version
```

Note: Downgrading may cause certain features to be unavailable or there may be compatibility issues, so proceed with caution and backup your files and data before downgrading.

---

Looks like `nbextensions` is not Compatible with notebook-6.5.3.

```
pip uninstall jupyter notebook                                                   ✔  108  14:06:04
Found existing installation: jupyter 1.0.0
Uninstalling jupyter-1.0.0:
  Would remove:
    /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/*
    /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter.py
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled jupyter-1.0.0
Found existing installation: notebook 6.5.3
Uninstalling notebook-6.5.3:
  Would remove:
    /opt/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-bundlerextension
    /opt/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-nbextension
    /opt/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
    /opt/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-serverextension
    /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook-6.5.3.dist-info/*
    /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/*
    /opt/miniconda3/share/applications/jupyter-notebook.desktop
    /opt/miniconda3/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/notebook.svg
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled notebook-6.5.3
```

### install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

```bash
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user 
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

Comment: Works with Ubuntu Mate 22.2